# Spring Data MongoDB Reactive - Dealing with findAll for a large number of documents?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

Let's say I have a `ReactiveMongoRepository` defined like this:

```java
@Repository
interface MyRepo extends ReactiveMongoRepository<MyDTO, String> {}
```

Given that the repository contains a lot of `MyData` documents (hundreds of thousands at least) and you do a simple "findAll()" followed by a deletion:

```java
myRepo.findAll()
      .doOnNext( myDto -> {
            System.out.println(myDto.message);
      })
      .flatMap( myDto -> {
            myRepo.deleteById(myDto.id);
      })
```

This will be executed roughly once a month.

Is it safe to use Spring Data / MongoDB like this when streaming large sets of data? Or is it recommended to using some sort of batching or pagination to avoid cursor issues etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer is it depends, but in your specific case in my opinion is no, at least not in your presented way

first of all, I guess that a find all operation, for all collection has very few sense. 
I suppose that find an use case that need to handle hundreds of thousands is near to impossible, supposing that you have implement a data ingestion pipeline ok you have handle an infinite stream of data but for this use case a more I can suggest a more suitable architecture like streaming with kafka using spring cloud stream for example.

The problem is not the possibility of handle many data because the mongo reactive drive is very performant and tuning the back pressure mechanism you should save your server but repeat using a find all in streaming so big is few applicable, probably if you should handle a stream of data a  messaging middleware with spring cloud stream may be the best option, imaging that you fire a find all ok your server and mogno probably will fine but your user will attend many hours before the request will finished, otherwise if the use case is a of line process as said before ok for processing an infinite data stream spring cloud stream may be the best option

**UPDATE**

Considering the use case of a lets say batch that should be ran one times per month I can say that the music change a lot.

Reading the code of Spring data reactive mongo I see that:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReactiveMongoRepository<T, ID> extends ReactiveSortingRepository<T, ID>, ReactiveQueryByExampleExecutor<T> {
....
}
```

instead of

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MongoRepository<T, ID> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, QueryByExampleExecutor<T> {
...
}
```

The key point of attention here is that the reactive version of the repository do not has the pagination feature in fact the name of base interface do not contains the word Paging, the key point here is the kind of technology.

In the blocking io the pagination is necessary for the model one thread per req and a so blocking pattern is dangerous for database application and so on busy a connection and the client for all the query is dangerous for timeout, load and so on and the split the query in page can help to not stress too much the system. But in a no blocking io the behavior is different you are attaching to a stream of data, the driver is a no blocking driver you do not use the classical mongo driver, spring data use the specific reactive mongo drive that is optimized for this job and it is based on a event loop model.

said that the key point here is that use a io intensive model for a off line profess probably is not so useful rather than safe, I mean using the reactive model is useful for software that are mainly io bound and with high traffic, the model support the high concurrency. But if your use case is a clean collection one times per month I guess that probably use reactive programming is safe since that is thought for support io intensive use case but in this case a classical batch blocking io model with pagination is a more suitable approach. The key point is i suppose that it should be safe the driver is thougth for manage a lot of data in high and streaming use case but it is useless use this approach for a batch use case

I hope that it can help you

Comment: Maybe I should add that this is something that'll be done once per month and after each document is read (i.e. printed to the console in the example) it'll be deleted.